# Binding on finish callback after Animated.Value has started animating?

Tags: react-native, animation

I'm in the midst of learning React Native's Animated library, but have stumbled across a problem for which I'm sure there must be a solution, but can't seem to find it.

**Context:**
I have a component which creates a new `Animated.Value` and starts animating it. I then want to pass that single value to sub components so they can all animate in their own away against this canonical value. But I also want some of these sub components to handle the `on finished` event.

**Currently:**
The only way [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated) explain handling the animation `on finished` event is by passing a callback function to `.start()`. But the parent component which starts the animation doesn't know how the multiple sub components intend to handle it.

**Question:**
Is there anyway to bind this callback after the animation has started? Something like `this.props.animatingValue.addOnFinished(...)` would be nice :)

Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding something fundamental. Is it a bad idea to pass `Animated.Value` instances as props? If so, what's a better way to approach this problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT (Request for code example):**
I'm just making this up as I go, so please forgive any syntax errors, but this should demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            animatedValue: new Animated.Value(0)
        }, () => {
            Animated.timing(this.state.animatedValue, {
                toValue: 1, 
                duration: 1000
            }).start()
        })
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.animatedValue ? (
            <View>
                <ChildOne animatedValue={this.state.animatedValue} />
                <ChildTwo animatedValue={this.state.animatedValue} />
                <ChildThree animatedValue={this.state.animatedValue} />
            </View>
        ) : null
    }
}

class ChildOne extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // What I'd like to do...
        this.props.animatedValue.onFinished(() => { /* ... something ... */ }
    }
    render() { /* interpolate some style against the animation, not important */ }
}

// same for ChildTwo and ChildThree ...
```

Comment: You can setstate indicating animation has finished.Is that not a viable option?

Comment: @ThakurKarthik That's a pretty creative work around. So the parent component would pass an `isFinishedAnimating` property to the child components and they would check that to determine if the animation has finished? I think that could work, but it feels strange to handle a temporal event from the `getDerivedStateFromProps` function...

Comment: I'm sorry,i am not that aware of how getDerivedStateFromProps works.Is it used to check for should render occur like shouldComponentUpdate() ?

Comment: @ThakurKarthik `getDerivedStateFromProps` replaces the deprecated `componentWillReceiveProps`. It's a way to translate props into state -- which I think would be needed in this case, or perhaps `shouldComponentUpdate` could work too?, to make sure we don't trigger the `onFinished` function multiple times. I.e., with your solution, once completed, the `isFinishedAnimating` flag would be set to `true` indefinitely so the sub component would need someway to react to -and track that it already reacted to - the prop change.

Comment: Before starting an animation set the isfinishedanimating to false and after to true.

Comment: I think the code would explain your problem more accurately. Can add minimal piece of your code?

Comment: @AbdumutalAbdusamatov Provided a basic code example of what I'd like to accomplish

Comment: @ThakurKarthik yes but if that component exists even after the animation completes, then it will just continuously say `true`. So there would need to be some additional complexity around ensuring that prop was only checked once / recognizing if the animation is restarted, etc... I think it could work, it's just not as elegant as one that actually responds to a single event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work. Use this approach in all your children.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.addAnimationEndedListener(this.onAnimationEnded);
    }

    onAnimationEnded = (finished)=>{
        /*The animation has Ended. Do what you want in the child here*/
    };
}
```

And then in parent,

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            animatedValue: new Animated.Value(0)
        }, () => {
            Animated.timing(this.state.animatedValue, {
                toValue: 1, 
                duration: 1000
            }).start(this.onAnimationEnded)
        });
        this.animationListeners = [];
    }

    addAnimationEndedListener = (listener)=>{
        this.animationListeners.push(listener);
    }

    onAnimationEnded = ({finished})=>{
        this.animationListeners.forEach(notifyListener=>{
            notifyListener(finished);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.animatedValue ? (
            <View>
                <ChildOne animatedValue={this.state.animatedValue} addAnimationEndedListener={this.addAnimationEndedListener} />
                <ChildTwo animatedValue={this.state.animatedValue} addAnimationEndedListener={this.addAnimationEndedListener} />
                <ChildThree animatedValue={this.state.animatedValue} addAnimationEndedListener={this.addAnimationEndedListener} />
            </View>
        ) : null
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically implementing our own little observer pattern. Very clever. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah. If RN decides to add support for something like this, they are probably gonna do the same. Cheers.